# How To Get Current Selected Tiles and Neighbour

Tags: c#, maps

I've 2D array that store each planes that instantiate using code.

```
Tile[][] map;
```

Then in `Update()`function, I try to `Raycast` and i can get the tile from `RaycastHit` game object.

How to get which Tile in my 2D array `map` is hovered base from `RaycastHit` without loop each tiles in array and check it ?

Comment: Welcome to gamedev! If you post relevant snippets of your code, it'll make it much easier for contributors to answer your question. Show us where you're at, and we can help you with the next step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your grid has uniform spacing, you can get this without raycasting, just using a bit of math.

Let's say `map[0][0]` has its center positioned at a worldspace point called `origin`, and `map[0][1]` is `spacing` units away from `origin` along the positive x-axis, and `map[1][0]` is `spacing` units away from `origin` along the positive y-axis.

Then...

```
var cursor = ConvertScreenCoordinatesToWorldCoordinates(mousePosition);

fromOrigin = cursor - origin;

int x = roundToInt(fromOrigin.x/spacing);
int y = roundToInt(fromOrigin.y/spacign);
```

Then you can get your neighbouring tiles by incrementing/decrementing `x` & `y` (and bounds checking to make sure you don'y try to walk off the edge of the map when starting from a tile right on the edge)